# How can I unambiguously identify game object in a scene?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to add interactive image objects on a scene from an array of objects I'm getting from JSON.

For example, I have this JSON:

```
{
  "graph": {
    "nodes": [
      {"name":"Catharsis", "type":"city",    "x":500, "y":200},
      {"name":"Arrakeen",  "type":"city",    "x":300, "y":400},
      {"name":"Mine_1",    "type":"facility","x":150, "y":450},
      {"name":"Belgorod",  "type":"city",    "x":700, "y":500}
    ],
    "paths": [
      {"from":"Arrakeen", "to":"Belgorod"},
      {"from":"Arrakeen", "to":"Mine_1"},
      {"from":"Arrakeen", "to":"Catharsis"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Nodes are locations, like cities and facilities.
This JSON is loaded as JS object into `mapData`

Then this JS draws objects in scene:

```
preload(){
  this.load.image('city','img/locations/city.png');
  this.load.image('facility','img/locations/facility.png');
}

create(){
  mapData.graph.paths.forEach(path => {
    var nodesFrom = mapData.graph.nodes
      .find(node => {
        return node.name == path.from
      }, path);
    var nodesTo = mapData.graph.nodes
      .find(node => {
        return node.name == path.to
      }, path);
    this.add.line(0, 0, nodesFrom.x, nodesFrom.y, nodesTo.x, nodesTo.y, 0x000000, 1)
      .setOrigin(0, 0);
  }, this);
  mapData.graph.nodes.forEach(node => {
    this.add.image(node.x,node.y,node.type)
      .setInteractive()
      .setScale(0.2);
    this.add.text(node.x,node.y,node.name,{fontSize:20,color:'#000'})
      .setOrigin(0.5, 0.3);
    this.input.on('gameobjectdown',this.onObjectClicked);
  }, this);
}
```

And this is the resulting scene:
[image: map scene]

But I want to show context menu of actions when one of the cities or facilities is clicked. With the list of menu items formed conditionally. For example, `Move to [city.name]` etc. But now all of the interactive objects send click events when one is clicked, so I need to somehow identify added images unambigously. Maybe add a key equal to the name of node, but how? And how to read it afterwards?

Comment: Inside event handlers, `event.target` will refer to the element that generated the event. So if you put an id or data attribute ( or anything else really ) onto each node, you can uniquely identify them inside the event handler. Then again, this sounds like something basically everyone using phaser will have to deal with, so I would be surprised if they do not have docs describing what the phaser way of event bubbling is.

Comment: Can you add your current code for `onObjectClicked`?

Comment: @brae It's just `onObjectClicked(pointer,gameObject){console.log('click')}`

Comment: @Shilly Right now docs on Phaser 3 are pretty raw, lacking of examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Samme](https://phaser.discourse.group/u/samme) from Phaser 3 forum, we have a solution:

```
this.add.image(node.x, node.y, node.type)
  .setName(node.name)
```

... which could be accessed like this: `gameObject.name`